# Why should be there the involvement of type promotion in this code?

Tags: c

In the code below the `sizeof(int)` will produce a `signed int` with a value of 4 bytes (suppose on a particular compiler) and `-1` is also `signed int`, then my answer should be **Yes** but it displays **No**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    if (sizeof(int) > -1)
        printf("Yes");
    else
        printf("No");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The result of sizeof is always unsigned, so -1 is also promoted to unsigned. The compiler should warn you about that. Enable all compiler warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: @n.m. okay I understood.

Comment: " the sizeof(int) will produce a signed int with a value of 4 bytes " - no, this is false. `sizeof` will produce a `size_t` value, which is unsigned, and not necessarily 4 bytes either.

Comment: I finally found this : The data type of the sizeof result is unsigned int or unsigned long depending upon the compiler implementation.

Comment: @anime: Just curious: What made you think that sizeof returns a signed value?

Comment: @anime: actually, IIRC all you know is that it's of some unsigned type. Nobody said that it's restricted to `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks for the correction, so it's of unsigned type only.But there are only three possible types of unsigned either int,floating or char, since sizeof() won't return a char, it will of either in int,float or double form only with associated modifiers?

Comment: @anime: there's no such a thing as `unsigned` floating point types, and anyhow the standard says that `sizeof` returns some unsigned *integral* type; I don't think it would be illegal for an implementation to return `unsigned char`. Anyhow, this is all irrelevant; all you need to know about the return type of `size_t` is that it's some unsigned integral type, for which a `typedef` (`size_t`) is provided in stddef.h.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it is the famous signed unsigned comparison. Here `-1` which is signed number when compared to unsigned numbers - promoted to an unsigned number resulting in a big magnitude value (`SIZE_MAX`). So it is always false.

The explanation why there would be type promotion here when comparing:

From standard [**§6.3.1.8**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8)

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.

Also from [**§6.5.8**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p3) under relational operators

> If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
>   conversions are performed.

And what sizeof returns?

Under The sizeof and _Alignof operators [**§6.5.3.4**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4)

> The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type) is
>   size_t, defined in  (and other headers).

And in section [**§7.19**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19) under Common definitions

> size_t which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof
>   operator;

To clarify a bit further when you are converting `-1` to `size_t` it will have the value (Basically modulo `SIZE_MAX+1`)

```
SIZE_MAX+1+(-1)
```

Also from standard [**§6.2.5**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9) (Explaining the conversion)

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because
>   **a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer
>   type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest
>   value that can be represented by the resulting type**.